# Adding values down an array

Tags: java, arrays, integer

I'm writing a class that does pen and paper multiplication.
I'm trying to add values down an array space. The workspace looks like:

```
52670000000000000000
00503000000000000000
00526700000000000000
00052510000000000000
```

So I want to add up `5,0,0,0` for the first column and store in first array index. Then `2,0,0,0` for the next. If it's over 10 then I just put the 0 into the array and carry the 1 over. My functions which extract the carry/rest of the numbers work fine.

I'm only counting in columns up to `rowCount+rowCount-1` which is how many columns across I can go which have actual values.

How can I get it to add down? So far i only can only get it to add across. (It's working properly for add across but I want to add down)!

```
 public static long addUpWorkspace(int rowCount, long[][]workspace){
    long carry = 0;
    long[]answer = new long[rowCount+rowCount-1];
    //for every row
    for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++){
        long value = 0;
        //for every column
        for (int j = 0; j < rowCount+rowCount-1; j++){
            value+=workspace[i][j];
        }
        value+=carry;

        System.out.println(value);
        //extract workspace value
        answer[i] = extractLast(value);
        //extract carry
        carry = extractAllButLast(value);

    }
```

Comment: Didn't understand why you used `rowCount+rowCount-1`

Comment: Got it, wait im looking for solution!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your `for` loop, what you are doing is, for each iteration of your outer loop you are keeping row number constant (outer loop) and increasing your column number (inner loop)  which explains why you are going across.

What you need to do is swap whatever is in round brackets of your outer `for` loop with whatever you have in the round brackets of your inner `for` loop

```
public static long addUpWorkspace(int rowCount,long[][]workspace){
long carry = 0;
long[]answer = new long[rowCount+rowCount-1];
//for every column
for (int j = 0; j < rowCount+rowCount-1; j++){
    long value = 0;
    //for every row
    for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++ ){
        value+=workspace[i][j];
    }
    value+=carry;

    System.out.println(value);
    //extract workspace value
    answer[i] = extractLast(value);
    //extract carry
    carry = extractAllButLast(value);

}
```